# Proving $\mathrm{B}$ to be a base of vector space $\mathrm{V}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathrm{W}$ be the vector subspace of $\mathrm{V}$ that is spanned by the base $\mathrm{B}$.

If I can show that $\dim{V} = \dim{W}$, does this imply that $\mathrm{B}$ spans $\mathrm{V}$, and so, that $\mathrm{B}$ is a base of $\mathrm{V}$?

My intuition says so. I don't need a formal proof, just to know if this is true.

Comment: "I don't need a formal proof, just to know if this is true" : that's sad...

Comment: @Surb The life of an undergraduate physicist is not sad, one just has to make use of intuition more than formal knowledge, at least at this level. A proof would be more than welcome, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. If W is a subspace of V and they have the same dimension then they are the same vector space.

Comment: I'll accept in 13 minutes. Thank you very much.

Comment: You wrote a statement that ceases to be true as soon as the dimension of $V$ is not finite.

Comment: True. Thought OP asked about spaces with finite dimension.

Comment: @Mark That is indeed so.